# How to get environment in config.yml?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

In app/config/config.yml I have for example:

```
samplebundle:
    link: "/admin"
```

How can I add for this current environment?

Something like that...

```
samplebundle:
    link: "{env}/admin"
```

If I am in dev env (app_dev.php) then I want the link to be with app_dev.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find environment parameter on `kernel.environment` by default

```
samplebundle:
    link: "%kernel.environment%/admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to put your configuration inside every config environment like this for example:

```
config_dev.yml

samplebundle:
    link: "dev/admin"
```

---

```
config_prod.yml

samplebundle:
    link: "prod/admin"
```

---

```
config_test.yml

samplebundle:
    link: "test/admin"
```

Another solution solution is to put in every parameters configuration a value like this:

```
parameters_dev.yml

parameters:
    env: 'dev'
```

And into your config.yml call this:

```
samplebundle:
        link: "%env%/admin"
```

Comment: The first half of your answer is spot on and really should be the accepted answer.  Your second solution goes into la la land.

Comment: the second solution is an exotic solution to avoid some use of kernel.environment :) but I adivse always the first solution because use the real power of configuration environment  @Cerad